# LeetCode: Binary Tree Level Order Traversal C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge

Please review for performance. and also naming convention

https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/

> Given a binary tree, return the level order traversal of its nodes'
>   values. (ie, from left to right, level by level).
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Given binary tree [3,9,20,null,null,15,7],
>     3
>    / \
>   9  20
>     /  \
>    15   7
>
> return its level order traversal as:
> [
>   [3],
>   [9,20],
>   [15,7]
> ]
> ```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using GraphsQuestions;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TreeQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class BinaryTreeLevelOrderTraversalTest
    {

        //      3
        //     / \
        //    9  20
        //   /  \
        //  15   7
        [TestMethod]
        public void TreeTest()
        {
            TreeNode root = new TreeNode(3);
            root.left = new TreeNode(9);
            root.right = new TreeNode(20);
            root.left.left = new TreeNode(15);
            root.left.right = new TreeNode(7);
            IList<IList<int>> res = BinaryTreeLevelOrderTraversalClass.LevelOrder(root);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(res[0].ToList(), new List<int>{3});
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(res[1].ToList(), new List<int>{9,20});
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(res[2].ToList(), new List<int>{15,7});
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void OneNodeTreeTest()
        {
            TreeNode root = new TreeNode(3);
            IList<IList<int>> res = BinaryTreeLevelOrderTraversalClass.LevelOrder(root);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(res[0].ToList(), new List<int> { 3 });
        }
    }

    public class BinaryTreeLevelOrderTraversalClass
    {
        public static IList<IList<int>> LevelOrder(TreeNode root)
        {
            List<IList<int>> res = new List<IList<int>>();
            if (root == null)
            {
                return res;
            }
            Queue<TreeNode> Q = new Queue<TreeNode>();

            Q.Enqueue(root);

            int counter = 0; // which level
            while (Q.Count > 0)
            {
                int children = Q.Count;
                res.Add(new List<int>());
                for (int i = 0; i < children; i++)
                {
                    var temp = Q.Dequeue();
                    res[counter].Add(temp.val);
                    if (temp.left != null)
                    {
                        Q.Enqueue(temp.left);
                    }
                    if (temp.right != null)
                    {
                        Q.Enqueue(temp.right);
                    }
                }
                counter++;
            }
            return res;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Avoid unnecessary variables

The `counter` variable is unnecessary.
For each level, you need just a `List<int> level`,
add the elements of the level to this list,
and then add this list to `res`.

By eliminating this variable, you also eliminate any concerns about the correctness of `res[counter].Add(temp.val);`.
With the code changed to `level.Add(temp.val)`,
the mental burden is reduced.

#### Use more descriptive names

- `res` could be `levels`
- `temp` could be `node`
- `LevelOrder` could be `GetLevels`
- `BinaryTreeLevelOrderTraversalClass` would be better without `Class`